# Storing a value of a pointer in eax

Tags: assembly, cheat-engine

Thanks for being here. After days of puzzling i cant figure out what goes wrong.

Current case:

```
mov eax, #0 // X Coords
```

This puts the value #0 into eax which is used as an X coord. This works.
But now i want it to listen to a different value, one not specified by me but by a pointer.

The pointer im talking about is:
[image: pointer_image]

```
[[0180C114+A34]+24]+68
```

This should point to a 4 byte address.

Im trying to do it like this and all sorts of variations but it doesnt work:

```
mov eax,[maplestory.exe+0180C114]
mov eax,[eax+A34]
mov eax,[eax+24]
mov eax,[eax+68] // should be the new X, since the pointer points to a value of 0
```

How can i get the value of that pointer and put it into eax?

Update:
I got it working when directly inputting the address where the pointer leads to. so the code was like this:

```
mov edx, [0D98370C]
mov [eax],edx// X
```

so i know that when i have the pointer working, it should work. But sadly i have no luck with the pointer yet.

Comment: That looks about right if what you say is true about the pointers. Is it a dword value?

Comment: i have updated my post.
I cant really give you an answer because of lack of knowledge but this is what i can tell you.
The eax accepts '#0' as value, so it sees it as a value instead of a hex or something, right?

Comment: You say it works with `0D98370C` ... but that value is nowhere in your picture so you have no chance to get that.

Comment: This is just my guess, but I don't see any `[]` in the `"MapleStory.exe"+0180C114` line, so how about using `mov eax,maplestory.exe+0180C114` instead of `mov eax,[maplestory.exe+0180C114]`?